# Create link in PHP with Get Parameters

Tags: php

This page is quite configurable with different parameters. So, it may be called like:

```
www.example.com/index.php?test=1&foo=3&bar=4
```

Now my question is, what is the idiom for generating a link to the current page but with one parameter changed?

For example, I'd like to change foo to 5, what's the easiest way to generate a link like:

```
www.example.com/index.php?test=1&foo=5&bar=4
```

I can loop through and do it manually, but I figured there would be some common idiom for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[array_merge()](http://lv.php.net/array_merge) is what you're looking for

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?<?php echo http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('foo' => 5)), '', '&amp;');?>">link text</a>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is why I love Stack Overflow.

Comment: +1 and [`http_build_query()`](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) - thanks for reminding me about that one!